# Reading text and writing to Excel in Java

Tags: java, excel

I have some code that puts new text on first line of a text document.  I need some code to read that first line from the text document, and then should write this text to the first cell, first column of an Excel document.  Then my code would put new text on the first line of the text document.  Need some code to read new text from the text document and this time put this text in second row, first column and the cycle repeats.

Can anyone give me some sample code to do this?

Comment: remove that // .. Is the whole question commented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [Apache POI-HSSF library](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) for reading and writing Excel files with Java. There are some [quick guides](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) to get you started.

Comment: I've used HSSF before; it's pretty slick.

Comment: Yep, it's quite nice to use. I particularly like the origins of the acronyms :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0516.html
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-06/04-qa-0629-excel.html

Please go through the above URL's

Comment: If the use case is really that simple also look at http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0586.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jexcelapi,it is more efficient than poi.